# Delete multiple objects Amazon s3 PHP SDK

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, amazon-s3

I'm having issues deleting multiple objects at once..

Using this library-
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel

- I have no issues with anything else using the library (putting, getting, deleting single objects, etc.)

  try {
  $s3 = AWS::get('s3');
  $s3->deleteObjects(array(
  'Bucket'  => $bucket,
  'Objects' => $json['attachmentArray']
  ));
  return "Success deleting files.";
  } catch (S3Exception $e) {
  return "There was an error.\n";
  }

deleteObjects Amazon Docs- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/DeletingMultipleObjectsUsingPHPSDK.html

I get returned `"Success deleting files.";`, but the files are not being deleted.

My bucket name is correct, and the `$json['attachmentArray']` is in the right format according to the docs (again, I have no issues with other areas like put, get, delete)

Where am I messing up?

Trying to give more info:

I am POSTing info from an Angular function to Laravel endpoint.

Here is the Angular function (Firebase URL hidden):

```
$scope.deleteFile = function() {
  
  var r=confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this task & of it's all attachments?");
  if (r==true)
    {
      var attachmentArray = [];

      var atttachData = new Firebase('https://*.firebaseio.com/attachments');
        atttachData.on('value', function(dataSnapshot) {  
           dataSnapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            var key   = childSnapshot.val().key;
            // attachmentArray.push(key); I tried this
               attachmentArray.push({Key:key});

            });
           });
                method: "POST",
                url: '/delete_task',
                data: {attachmentArray:attachmentArray},
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
           }).success(function(data){
              console.log(data);
           });
    } 
}
```

And here is my Laravel controller that I am trying to make deleteObjects (with updated code from @Kevin Florida:

```
 public function delete_task() {
    $request = Request::instance();
    $task = $request->getContent(); 
    $json = json_decode($task, TRUE); 
    $bucket ='bucketname/team1';

    // return $json['attachmentArray'];
    $s3 = AWS::get('s3');
    if(!$s3->deleteObjects(array(
                'Bucket'  => $bucket,
                'Objects' => $json['attachmentArray']
            ))) {
     return "error";
    } else {
     return "success";
    }
}
```

Now this returns a 500 server error.. I think I'm formatting `$json['attachmentArray'];` incorrectly? I'm not sure.

Angular function

```
$scope.deleteFile = function() {
  
  var r=confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this task & of it's all attachments?");
  if (r==true)
    {
      var attachmentArray = [];

      var atttachData = new Firebase('https://***/attachments');
        atttachData.on('value', function(dataSnapshot) {  
           dataSnapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            var url   = childSnapshot.val().url;
            var name  = childSnapshot.val().name;
            var id    = childSnapshot.val().id;
            var key   = childSnapshot.val().key;              
            attachmentArray.push(key);
            });
           });
      $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: '/delete_task',
                data: {team:$scope.team,attachmentArray:attachmentArray,lastSegment:lastSegment},
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
           }).success(function(data){
              console.log(data);
           });          
    } 
}
```

Laravel controller

```
public function delete_task() {
    $s3 = AWS::get('s3');
    $task = Input::all();
    $bucket ='teamite/team'.$task['team'];
    
    //make the array for Objects on this side
    foreach ($task['attachmentArray'] as $value) {
        $array[] = array('Key' => $value);
      }
     // return $task['attachmentArray'][0];

      $result = $s3->deleteObjects(array(
          'Bucket' => 'teamite/team1',
          'Objects' => $array
      ));

      return $result;
}
```

And I log this response in the console from Amazon:

```
=====================
Debug output of model
=====================

Model data
-----------

This data can be retrieved from the model object using the get() method of the model   (e.g. $model->get($key)) or accessing the model like an associative array (e.g. $model['key']).

[Deleted] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Key] => 4700pzgds4i_ad.jpg
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [Key] => xxvu29ms4i_ad.jpg
            )

    )

[RequestId] => 477F0DA04101D82E
```

So it seems to be working correctly now. But the objects are not being deleted?
What else am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not enough information for me to help, but I would suggest you look at file ownership permissions on the server.

Comment: What more info can I provide you with? It's a public bucket. I have no issues with deleting single objects from this bucket.

Comment: what is the value of $json['attachmentArray'] ?

Comment: Also, you are returning "Success deleting files." no matter what

Comment: when i `return $json['attachmentArray'];` before the s3 if statement, my console looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/ojTNZqs.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It actually looks like you are not referencing the files (S3 objects) correctly. The formatting of the request is fine, but the bucket name and keys may be wrong.

Looking at:

```
$bucket = 'teamite/team'.$task['team'];
```

Is your bucket called "teamite/team1" or just "teamite"? Keep in mind that S3 has a flat structure. There are no "subbuckets". If you have things laid out in a nested file structure, then the paths, or pseudo-folders, need to be included as part of the key.

For example, in this imaginary URL to an object in S3: `http://s3.amazonaws.com/all-of-my-things/photos/2013/12/photo0005.jpg`

The bucket is `all-of-my-things`, and the key is `photos/2013/12/photo0005.jpg`.

The `deleteObjects()` call you are making is returning successfully because of the idempotent nature of S3 operations. If you delete an object multiple times, it will return successfully every time. What you are seeing here is that you are deleting objects using the wrong keys. Those keys don't exist, and therefore are already deleted.

Hopefully this helps. Don't be afraid to reach out on the [module's issue tracker](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel/issues) or directly on the [SDK's issue tracker](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues) for problems like this when you are working directly with the SDK objects.

Comment: The bucket name is `teamite` and the file is located in a folder of `team1`. Are you sure that folders need to be included into the filename? I will definitely check this out.. but am a little confused, because the single `deleteObject` file use the folder name as part of the bucket, not file name. Will report back shortly.

Comment: You da man. I included the folder name with the key, and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

To delete s3 file use it

It work for me -

```
 $s3 = AWS::get('s3');
 $s3->deleteMatchingObjects('Your Bucket Name', 'File name to delete');
```

Answer (score 1):

For testing try:

```
if(!$s3->deleteObjects(array(
            'Bucket'  => $bucket,
            'Objects' => $json['attachmentArray']
        ))) {
 return "error";
} else {
 return "success";
}
```

catch will only return "There was an error" if an exception occurs, not if the deleteObjects() method returns false

Comment: I've replaced my original code with yours. Silly mistake on my part.
I believe I must be formatting my `$json['attachmentArray'];` incorrectly, because I now get a 500 server error. I updated my original question in attempt to provide more context. Thanks for the help so far Kevin!

Answer (score 1):

For those who come across this question in the future and need to delete multiple objects on S3, you can follow this solution:

```
$objectsArray = [
        ['Key' => 'photo1.jpg'],
        ['Key' => 'photo2.jpg'],
        // Add more objects as needed
];

$s3->deleteObjects([
    'Bucket' => $bucket_name,
    'Delete' => [
        'Objects' => $objectsArray,
    ],
]);
```

In OP, $json['attachmentArray'] is same as objectsArray.
ps. as @Jeremy Lindblom mentioned if you have a nested file structure make sure you use the full path on the key.

code sample tested on aws-sdk-php v 3.180.0 with php8

for more details check: [DeleteObjects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example_s3_DeleteObjects_section.html)