# Delete folder that contains files from s3 bucket php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Im trying to delete a folder in an s3 bucket that is located in a folder called CreativeEngine the folder structure looks like this CreativeEngine/8943
I want to delete the folder with the called 8943 but it contains files within it. Do I need to do some kind of loop to delete the files first or can I delete the folder? I tried this but it didn't work

```
    <?php 
$itemId=$_GET['id'];
    require('s3/vendor/autoload.php');
        use Aws\S3\S3Client;
        use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;
        // AWS Info
        $bucketName = 'mybucket';
        $IAM_KEY = 'mykey';
        $IAM_SECRET = 'mysecret';
        // Connect to AWS
            $s3 = S3Client::factory(
                array(
                    'credentials' => array(
                        'key' => $IAM_KEY,
                        'secret' => $IAM_SECRET
                    ),
                    'version' => 'latest',
                    'region'  => 'us-east-2'
                )
            );


    $s3Destination='CreativeEngine/'.$itemId;
    $keyName = $s3Destination;

    try{
    $s3->deleteObject(array(
        'Bucket' => $bucketName,
        'Key'    => $keyName
    ));       
    } catch (S3Exception $e) {
    $data['message']='<li>error'.$e->getMessage().'</li>';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: S3 doesn't actually have folders. It only have files with `xxx/` in in the file names (which viewers might show as folders). So you need to delete all files.

Comment: thats great I realize they aren't actually called folders its actually objects according to the documentation but do I need to do some kind of loop and if so how would I go about doing that?

Comment: If you get a list of the files, you should be able to delete them all in a batch. Check this post out: https://serverfault.com/questions/679989/most-efficient-way-to-batch-delete-s3-files. Also check out this post and see if that helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20704921/delete-multiple-objects-amazon-s3-php-sdk

Comment: Flysystem is a great file management lib, with adapters for S3, and it CAN delete directories recursively. Take a look https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/docs/adapter/aws-s3/  That's the adapter, and here's what you can do with it https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/docs/usage/filesystem-api/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible via **delete_all_objects($bucket, $pcre)**, where `$pcre`is an optional *Perl-Compatible Regular Expression (PCRE) to filter the names against* (default is `PCRE_ALL`, which is  `"/.*/i"`), e.g.:

```
$s3 = new AmazonS3();
$response = $s3->delete_all_objects($bucket, "#myDirectory/.*#");
```